# Error deserializing JSON Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I have the following JSON:

```
{"workspace": {
  "name":"Dallas",
   "dataStores":"http://.....:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Dallas/datastores.json",
   "coverageStores":"http://.....:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Dallas/coveragestores.json",
   "wmsStores":"http://....:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Dallas/wmsstores.json"}}
```

And I´m trying to deserialize int this class:

```
 class objSON {
        public string workspace { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string dataStores { get; set; }
        public string coverageStores { get; set; }
        public string wmsStores { get; set; }}

 objWS_JSON deserContWS = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objWS_JSON>(data);
           var coberturas = deserContWS.coverageStores;
           var almacenesDatos = deserContWS.dataStores;
           var almacenesWMS = deserContWS.wmsStores;
           var nombre = deserContWS.name;
```

And I get the following error:

**Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.String'.**

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your json is incorrect for the class structure you've provided.  The json implies that name, dataStores, coverageStores and wmsSTores are children of a workspace class.  I think the class structure you want is this:

```
public class workspace
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string dataStores { get; set;}
    public string coverageStores { get; set;}
    public string wmsStores {get; set;}
}

public class objSON
{
    public workspace workspace {get; set;}
}
```

try that, if that data structure is not what you are after then you need to change your json.

Ok I've just tried in a sample app and seems to work fine.  Here is the code I used:

```
    class Program
    {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

               string str = @"{""workspace"": {
                  ""name"":""Dallas"",
                  ""dataStores"":""http://.....:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Dallas/datastores.json"",
                  ""coverageStores"":""http://.....:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Dallas/coveragestores.json      "",
                  ""wmsStores"":""http://....:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Dallas/wmsstores.json""}}";

                 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objSON>(str);

    }

}

public class workspace
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string dataStores { get; set; }
    public string coverageStores { get; set; }
    public string wmsStores { get; set; }
}

public class objSON
{
    public workspace workspace { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I solve the error but my elements are null

Comment: objWS_JSON deserContWS = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objWS_JSON>(data);
           var coberturas = deserContWS.coverageStores;
           var almacenesDatos = deserContWS.dataStores;
           var almacenesWMS = deserContWS.wmsStores;
           var nombre = deserContWS.name;

Comment: Sorry Kevin I was failed with the deserialization I forget change, now is working!. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the JSON, `workspace` *contains* all the rest, so you should have something like:

```
class Container {
    public Workspace workspace { get; set; }
}

class Workspace {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string dataStores { get; set; }
    public string coverageStores { get; set; }
    public string wmsStores { get; set; }
}
```

At the very least that matches the structure of the JSON - whether it'll work or not is another matter :)

Comment: so `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(data);` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yup, I'd expect so.

Comment: Thanks, in data I change the slash \ of my JSON by this /

Comment: Yes, because data is the JSON clean whithout backslashes

Comment: @JMG: So where do the backslashes come into it at all? It's unclear why you've suddenly brought them up... you shouldn't need to replace anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the JSON object (it is perhaps better if you laid out your `{` and `}` a little more clearly), you'll see that it is trying to serialize all that data in to the `workspace` field, and not the other properties.  I would expect your object to look something more like:

```
{
   "workspace": "whatever",
   "name":"Dallas",
   "dataStores":"http://.....:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Dallas/datastores.json",
   "coverageStores":"http://.....:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Madrid/coveragestores.json",
   "wmsStores":"http://....:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Madrid/wmsstores.json"
}
```